# How to change shipping rate based on shipping address

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, shipping-address

I have added a new shipping method module for my magento store. This module allows the user to set shipping rates based on shipping address country.
I have added an observer on customer shipping address save after, the code is below.
In `config.xml` I added new event.

```
<events>
             <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_address_after>
                <observers>
                    <zones>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>zones/observer</class>
                        <method>getShippingMethods</method>
                    </zones>
                </observers>
            </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_address_after>
        </events>
```

After that I have dispatched the event in `OnepageController > SaveShipping` method like,

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_address_after', array('page' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()));
```

This calls the observer when I save my shipping address. But I have no idea how to change the shipping method charge as per the shipping address country.
I have used this thread http://www.opencart60s.com/magento/changing-or-set-shipping-price-on-fly-from-event-or-observer-in-magento.html-13407.html to change the shipping cost. But without success.
I need to change my shipping flat rate as per the country.
I have already created the module which will store the country and shipping rate details. I can get the shipping rate using that module. Now, I just have to update the flat rate value with the custom shipping rate value.
Please help me setting my flat rate as per the country code. Thanks..

Comment: If you want to change the shipping rate based on the address, why don't you just use table rates? If you don't want to build such a CSV used by tablerates, you can have a look on https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from this link here : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/316685/
In my observer  I added below code to change my shipping rates as per country selection in shipping address.

```
class Pnk_Zones_Model_Observer
{
    public function getShippingMethods($observer)
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quoteid=$quote->getId(); 
        if($quoteid) {                    
        try{
                $address=$quote->getShippingAddress();
                if($address->getAddressType()=='shipping'){
            //    echo '<pre>'; print_r($events->getQuoteAddress()->getData()); exit;
                //$price=40;
                $countryId = $address->getCountry();
                //Code to get Shipping rate from my zone module //
                $shippingRateCollection = Mage::getModel('zones/zones')->getCollection();
                $shippingRateCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');
                $shippingRateCollection->getSelect()->where("find_in_set('".$countryId."', `countries`)");


                foreach ($shippingRateCollection as $shipping){
                    $price = $shipping->getShippingRate();
                }
//              echo "Price = ".$price;
                // Find if our shipping has been included.
                $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                         ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

                foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
                    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
                        // Check with your custom shipping method code
                if($rate->getCode() == 'zones'){
                            $rate->setPrice($price);
                            $rate->save();
               }
                    }
                }
                    $this->collectTotals($quote,$price);
                }            
                $quote->collectTotals();
            } catch (Exception $e) {            
                Mage::logException($e);
                $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }   

    public function collectTotals($quote,$price){
        $quoteid=$quote->getId(); 
        $shippingcode='freeshipping_freeshipping';
        if($quoteid) {                    
                try{
                $quote->setSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingcode)/* ->collectTotals() */->save();
                $quote->save();
                foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
                    $address->setSubtotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                    $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                    $address->collectTotals();

                    $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                    $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );

                    $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

                    $address->setShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
                    $address->save();
                }

                    $response['message'] = 'Succcess';
                } catch (Exception $e) {            
                        Mage::logException($e);
                        $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                 }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thebod built a module which does this for you, might help:
https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates